# Finding $\sin\theta$ given $\cot\theta$, and finding $\cot\theta$ given $\tan\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How can I find the following?

- Find $\sin\theta$, where $\cot\theta = 3/4$
- Find $\cot\theta$, where $\tan\theta = 1.5$

Is there a good site that you could recommend to show how to do these conversions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question #1. Well, the cotangent function is defined as the adjacent side over the opposite side: $\cot\theta=\frac{adj}{opp}$. The sine function is define as the opposite side over the hypotenuse: $\sin\theta=\frac{opp}{hyp}$. Since we know the ratio of the two sides of the right triangle given to us as the value of the cotangent function, we can find the third one—the hypotenuse.

$$
hyp^2 = 4^2 + 3^2 \implies\\
hyp=\sqrt{4^2 + 3^2} \implies\\
hyp=5
$$

So, now we can find the value of the sine function:
$$
\sin \theta = \frac{opp}{hyp} = \frac{4}{5}
$$

Question #2: the cotangent function is the reciprocal of the tangent function: $\cot\theta=\frac{1}{\tan\theta}$. So, this problem is really just about plugging in what is given as part of the problem, namely, $\tan\theta = 1.5$:

$$
\cot\theta=\frac{1}{\tan\theta}=\frac{1}{1.5}=\frac{1}{3/2}=\frac{2}{3}
$$

Question #3. Here's a [good website](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry) to get you started in trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try to Draw a right triangle first, then you can apply the formula for sine to find another length, then you can find another value of the trig function.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cot(\theta)=\frac{3}{4}$, let $\triangle ABC$ with $m\angle ABC=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $m\angle ACB=\theta$. Then $|AB|=4$ and $|BC|=3$ by the definition of $\cot$. By Pythagora’s Theorem one has $|AC|=5$, therefore $\sin(\theta)=\frac{4}{5}$.

On the other since $\tan(\theta)=1.5$ then $$\cot(\theta)=\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}=\frac{1}{1.5}=\frac{2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

By Pitagora’s theorem: the length that missing is $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=\sqrt{25}=5$. So $\tan \theta =3/2$ and hence $\cot \theta=2/3$.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- Shown are the two points on the unit circle for which $\cot \theta = \dfrac 34$.

  - If $\theta$ is in the first quadrant, then $\sin \theta = \dfrac 45$.
  - If $\theta$ is in the third quadrant, then $\sin \theta = -\dfrac 45$.
- If $\tan \theta = 1.5 = \frac 32$, then

  - $\cot \theta = \dfrac{1}{\tan \theta} = \dfrac 23$, regardless of whether $\theta$ is in the first or the third quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the right triangle $\triangle ABC$ such that $AB \perp BC$. By the definition of the sine of the angle $BCA$, let’s call it $\theta$, we have that $BC=3$ and $AB=4$ since $\cot(\theta)=3/5$.

Applying Pitágoras’s theorem one gets that $$AC=\sqrt{3^2+4^2}=5 .$$ Therefore $\sin(\theta)=\frac{4}{5}$.

On the other hand, since $$\cot(\theta)=\frac{1}{\tan(\theta)}$$ and $\tan(\theta)=1.5=3/2$ then $\cot(\theta)=3/2$.